# Simple iOS particle emitter

Tags: ios, animation, sdk, core-animation, particles

Is there a simple way to do a bunch of 2d particle images using core animation like the star particle animation in Draw Something?

[Particle animation in Draw Something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXd2o.png)

I found this link which get's me 90% of the way there.  It shows how to emit particles using UIImage which is just what I need.  I just need some help tweaking the particles so they spew out like the Draw Something button and not like their fire example and I want to randomize the colors of the particles and make them glow.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just found this which got me the rest of the controls I wanted.  The variable I was looking for on the emitters was yAccelleration.  Set it to a positive number to make it go down.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Fireworks/Listings/AppController_m.html

Hope this helps someone else!